# Write hexadecimal to file in C (not ASCII)

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to convert some binary strings to hexadecimal values and write it directly into the file. I mean the values should be visible only through hex editor and I do not care about ASCII text in the file.

Here is part of my code:

```
unsigned int value;
char p[4];
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("file.txt","wb+");

//sprintf(p, "\\x%x", hex);

value = strtol("10010011", NULL, 2);
fwrite(&value, strlen(p), 1, fp);

//fwrite(p, strlen(p), 1, fp);
```

I tried to use fwrite to write the integer to file. It seems to work, but it will write 4 bytes hex (padding with 00s) instead of 1 byte. I also tried to print a string starting with "\x" and write the string to file (comment out this piece of code), but it will write in ASCII format including "\x" to file that is not what I want. Does anyone have an idea about how to do this or what's wrong with my code? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what "hexadecimal values" means.   A hexadecimal value is an ascii string that represents a number using hexadecimal characters 0-9A-F, just as a decimal value is an ascii string that represents a number using decimal characters 0-9.  Are you actually trying to write the binary data to the file?

Comment: @DaleWilson - _hexadecimal value is an ascii string_,...  Perhaps:  _a hexadecimal number is an integer value represented in base 16 using the 16 ASCII characters 0-9A-F and sometimes x. (eg. 0x1AD3)_.  Just a nit.  equating a value to ASCII string seemed wrong somehow in this context. :)

Comment: @ryyker I was being concise and using the OP's words.  Otherwise I might say: Not all ASCII strings are hexadecimal representations of numbers, but all hexadecimal representations of numbers are character strings containing the above mentioned characters.  In modern times these are almost always ASCII or Unicode character strings (rarely EBCDIC or Baudot).

Comment: @DaleWilson - No problem.  I was just struck funny by the phrase.  The idea you wanted to convey, I believe was conveyed :)  Im not sure I did any better in my attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `strlen` as that gives the length of the `string` which is 8 in this case, so it writes 8 bytes. use `sizeof(value)` instead.
Also, you are using an `int` data type, the size of which could vary depending on your platform. If you want to just write the byte, use an unsigned char. So your code would be:

```
unsigned char value;
char p[4];
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("file.txt","wb+");
value = strtol("10010011", NULL, 2);
fwrite(&value, sizeof(value), 1, fp);

//fwrite(p, strlen(p), 1, fp);
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: `;` needed after `fp = fopen("file.txt","wb+")`.  :)

Comment: aarghh... i always miss that :-)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding *I also tried to print a string starting with "\x" and write the string to file*:

The indicated sections will allow you to test placing both string and binary representation of a hexadecimal value, 0x93 (10010011) into a text file: (uncomment the section you want to test)

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned int value;
    char buf[10];
    char p[4];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("file.txt","wb+");//"wb+" will allow either text or binary write (intended for binary)
    value = strtol("10010011", NULL, 2);
    /*writes binary value to file*/
    //fwrite(&value, sizeof(value), 1, fp);      //uncomment to test value to file
    /*writes string representation to file*/
    sprintf(buf, "\\x%x", value);                //uncomment to test string to file
    fputs(buf, fp);                              //
    return 0;

}
```